# Including GAlib library to C++

Tags: c++, galib

I'm having troubles adding GAlib to my project in C++. I followed these steps:

https://github.com/htoooth/galib247CompileResult

I tried to include the compiled result and compiling on my own using nmake.. I think Im doing something wrong... here is what I did:

1. Following the procedures until I get two folders "include"
   (inside of which many header and source files) and "library" (inside
   of which one lib "ga.lib"). while making these, I got many warnings
   of this : "Option GX has been deprecated and will be removed in
   future release"
2. Project properties>C/C++>General>Additional # using
   Directories>Add the path to "include folder" (I tried adding the
   path to Additional include Directories or even both, the same
   problem)
3. Project properties>Linker>General>Additional Library Directories>
   Add path to "ga.lib"
4. Project properties>Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies> Add
   "ga.lib" to the list

Always I get an error of "Cannot open file source XXX" which is inside include folder. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try opening the missing file in your Solution Explorer?

Comment: yes, it opens with no probs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I left the default code generation option "runtime library" as Multi-threaded dll.. once I changed it to "Multi-threaded debug", the problem was solved.